# how to convert this java code `Collectors.toMap()` to kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

// this is java code

```
 Map<String, List<List<Object>>> tableRows = newSchema
                .values()
                .stream()
                .map(Column::tableName)
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> new ArrayList()));
```

// this is kotlin code

```
val tableRows = newSchema.values.map { it.tableName() }.distinct()???????????
```

and i don't know how to write this...

Comment: what is the type of `newSchema`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val tableRows = newSchema.values.map { it.tableName() }.distinct().associateWith { ArrayList<List<Any>>() }
```